# SQL Server - Sum Values and adding to all identical IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a SQL beginner (obviously). I have the following situation where I am stuck.

As I am going to deduplicate the following table in a second step, I want assure first that all spendings of users are summed up before.

I am only able to work with SELECT statements. Any hints with what to start here are great.

```
ID | Firstname | Lastname | spending
---+-----------+----------+-----------
01 | John      | Smith    |    5 
01 | John      | Smith    |    2
01 | John      | Smith    |  
02 | Tobi      | Miller   |  
02 | Tobi      | Miller   |  
02 | Tobi      | Miller   |  
03 | Kelly     | Schult   |    3 
03 | Kelly     | Schult   |    2 
03 | Kelly     | Schult   |    1
```

Desired result:

```
ID | Firstname | Lastname | spendings
---+-----------+----------+-----------
01 | John      | Smith    |    7 
01 | John      | Smith    |    7
01 | John      | Smith    |    7 
02 | Tobi      | Miller   |  
02 | Tobi      | Miller   |  
02 | Tobi      | Miller   |  
03 | Kelly     | Schult   |    6 
03 | Kelly     | Schult   |    6 
03 | Kelly     | Schult   |    6
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Window Functions:

```
SELECT ID,
       Firstname, Lastname,
       SUM(spending) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Spendings
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would group by ID and sum the spendings column:

```
 SELECT *, SUM(spendings) FROM YourTable GROUP BY ID
```

Also, this will remove the duplicate results.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server includes a number of [windowed functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) that you can use to partition your data.

In this example, I've combined the [sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) function with an over clause.

```
-- Table vars are a great way to share test data.
DECLARE @Example TABLE
(
    ID          INT,
    FirstName   VARCHAR(50),
    LastName    VARCHAR(50),
    Spending    MONEY
);

-- Values from OP.
INSERT INTO @Example
(
    ID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Spending
)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'Smith', 5),
    (1, 'John', 'Smith',  2),
    (1, 'John', 'Smith', 0),
    (2, 'Tobi', 'Miller', 0),
    (2, 'Tobi', 'Miller', 0),
    (2, 'Tobi', 'Miller', 0),
    (3, 'Kelly', 'Schult', 3),
    (3, 'Kelly', 'Schult', 2),
    (3, 'Kelly', 'Schult', 1)
;

-- Sub totals.
SELECT
    ID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SUM(Spending) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Spendings
FROM
    @Example
;
```

You mention that you plan to dedup your data in a second step.  My advice is to always tidy your data first.  Working around complexities or flaws in a dataset always makes later steps more complicated.  In this case a good first query might be:

```
-- Alternative, clear and total in one step.
SELECT
    ID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SUM(Spending) AS Spendings
FROM
    @Example
GROUP BY
    ID,
    FirstName,
    LastName
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (ID INT, FIRST_N VARCHAR(20),LAST_N VARCHAR(20),SPENDING INT)

INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES (01 , 'John' , 'Smith' , 5 ),
(01 , 'John' , 'Smith' , 2),
(01 , 'John' , 'Smith',0 )  ,
(02 , 'Tobi' , 'Miller',0 ) , 
(02 , 'Tobi' , 'Miller',0) ,
(02 , 'Tobi' , 'Miller',0 )  ,
(03 , 'Kelly' , 'Schult' , 3 ),
(03 , 'Kelly' , 'Schult' , 2 ),
(03 , 'Kelly' , 'Schult' , 1)


;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT T.ID,T.FIRST_N,T.LAST_N,SUM(SPENDING) AS SPENDING
FROM @TAB T
GROUP BY T.ID,T.FIRST_N,T.LAST_N
)

SELECT T.ID,T.FIRST_N,T.LAST_N,C.SPENDING 
FROM @TAB T
INNER JOIN CTE  C ON C.ID = T.ID
```

OUTPUT

```
ID  FIRST_N LAST_N  SPENDING
1   John    Smith   7
1   John    Smith   7
1   John    Smith   7
2   Tobi    Miller  0
2   Tobi    Miller  0
2   Tobi    Miller  0
3   Kelly   Schult  6
3   Kelly   Schult  6
3   Kelly   Schult  6
```

Comment: As I said to Jayasurya Satheesh, there's no need to scan the table twice here. Both Window Functions and Aggregate functions can avoid the extra IO.